# ENOENT: no such file or directory, This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: reactjs

npm install -g create-react-app, Why it is mandatory to write before creating any react project. If I globally install npm then why it is required to install npm another time for another folder or project.

It always shows the below error:-

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NAFFY KAUSAR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-23T15_12_49_522Z-debug.log
PS E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome> npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\NAFFY KAUSAR\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\NAFFY KAUSAR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js

- create-react-app@3.4.1
  updated 1 package in 24.341s
  npm ERR! code ENOENT
  npm ERR! syscall open
  npm ERR! path E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\package.json
  npm ERR! errno -4058
  npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome\package.json'
  npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
  npm ERR! enoent
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\NAFFY KAUSAR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-23T15_19_27_276Z-debug.log
  PS E:\AvatarDemo\AvatarDemoAwesome> create-react-app AvatarAwesome

Comment: You have to use `npx create-react-app my-app-name` if you got `npm install -g create-react-app` from a tutorial then find another one.

Comment: Ok, but why it is mandatory to write(npm install -g create-react-app) before making any project. Please clear my little bit of confusion.

Comment: You should not need to write `npm install -g create-react-app` before every project; the `-g` flag will install the package globally on your machine, so you can easily run `create-react-app` in any directory without needing to re-install.

The general advice is to uninstall this completely however (`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`), and instead create new projects by running `npx create-react-app app-name` so that you are always getting the up-to-date release when setting up a project.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a different way of looking at this the create react package is a website sample site builder.  The create react package generates a skeleton app for you with everything you need to build a react app. To build a sample website you need to use the package and pass in a name:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

The above command installs the builder

```
 npx create-react-app CustomName
```

Generates a website from the builder

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to use `create-react-app` when making a React project. It's handy to use it because it initializes the project for you and might save you some work though. For a `node` project you need a `package.json` file and this will create one for you if you run it along with some default dependencies needed by React.

Note that the command you talk about (npm install -g create-react-app) just asks `npm` to install the `create-react-app` module globally on your computer. It does not run the tool for you.  You can run it with the command `npx create-react-app my-app` which will create a folder called `my-app` with a `package.json` and other files in it. It's just a convenience though. You can do all of this file setup yourself if you want to.

The error you're getting is from trying to run `npm start` (or a similar command) in a folder that does not have a `package.json` file yet. A `package.json` file is mandatory for `npm` and `node` to know what to do.

So the mandatory action is to create a `package.json` file. The `create-react-app` utility is just a handy way to do that if you are making a React app.

Comment: I get this error (no package.json file) when running 'npx create-react-app movie-app'. Not when I run 'npm start'

Comment: running `npx create-react-app` should have created a folder called movie-app which contains `package.json`. The package.json is there in `movie-app/package.json` but doesn't have much in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar error and terminal (foolishly, on my part) was is a parent directory instead of the correct one (where `package.json` was correctly located).

All I did in terminal was `cd [insert correct directory name here, overwriting brackets]` and that corrected the problem.